# Ubuntu how to add deamon to start

Tags: startup, services

**I have Ubuntu 18.04**

I have bitcoinz node installed on my Ubuntu. Generally I start it with this command:

```
/home/user1/bitcoinz/src/bitcoinzd -datadir=/home/user1/bitcoinz/data > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
```

I start it as user1, not as root. How to add starting this deamon at the start of the server? To do this I can use command `sudo update-rc.d xxx defaults`, but how to add parameters and running as user1 ?

Comment: What is the ubuntu version?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start your command using cron.

- Open terminal
- Run `crontab -e` to run command as user1
- Add to the end:

  ```
  * * * * * /bin/date >> /home/user1/mydate
  ```

to check if /home/user1/mydate file appears and you could see its content

- Create `~/scripts` folder: `mkdir ~/scripts`
- Add your command to `/home/user1/scripts/bitcoinz` script: `vim.tiny ~/scripts/bitcoinz` (hit <kbd>**i**</kbd> for editing)

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  /home/user1/bitcoinz/src/bitcoinzd -datadir=/home/user1/bitcoinz/data > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
  ```

Save and exit (For `vim.tiny`: <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit eiditing mode, then `:wq` to save and exit)

- Make script executable: `chmod +x ~/scripts/bitcoinz`
- Run `crontab -e` and add to the end:
  @reboot /home/user1/scripts/bitcoinz

You could set parameters inside of script. You could also run `cron` as root user using `sudo crontab -e`, so it could start as root after reboot.

To make a service as you said in title, do the next:

- Create the new systemd service:

  ```
  sudo vim.tiny /lib/systemd/system/bitcoinz.service
  sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/bitcoinz.service /etc/systemd/system/
  ```

  Paste the next to it:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Start bitcoinz
  After=suspend.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/home/user1/scripts/bitcoinz
  RestartSec=10s
  Restart=on-failure

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Enable and start the newly created service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable bitcoinz && sudo systemctl start bitcoinz
  ```

To work with service as user:

- Create the directory `mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user`
- Create ubitcoinz.service file there: `touch ~/.config/systemd/user/ubitcoinz.service`
- Edit it and add there entries as in previous file
- Use `--user` option to work with it

  ```
  systemctl --user daemon-reload
  systemctl --user enable ubitcoinz
  systemctl --user start ubitcoinz
  ```
- Output of bitcoinz command could be viewed using `journalctl -u ubitcoinz`
- To start user service not only if user logs in, but at boot:

  ```
  loginctl enable-linger user1
  ```
- Check status:  `loginctl user-status user1`

[Reference](https://vic.demuzere.be/articles/using-systemd-user-units/)

Comment: @user535733 changed answer